# Imagick create svg file without includin external image

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to programmatically create some svg and I need to put inside it some avatars.

```
    $usmap = 'https://domain.it/tor/image/tavoli/avatar.svg';
    $im = new \Imagick();
    $svg = file_get_contents($usmap);

    $pdo = DB::getPdo();
    foreach($player as $key => $id){
       $file_path = 'https://domain.it/tor/image/download/player'.$id.'.jpg';

         $svg = preg_replace(
           '/id="player'.($key+1).'" xlink:href="svg"/'
           , 'id="player'.($key+1).'"xlink:href="https://domain.it/tor/image/download/'.$file_path.'"'
           , $svg);
            
    }

    $im->readImageBlob($svg);

    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    file_put_contents('image/tavoli/tavolo_'.$tavoloId.'.jpeg', $im);
```

Te result is the original image without avatars in it. I have the life and they are accessible.

What can be wrong?

EDIT:
I tryed this solution too

xlink:href="'.imageToBase64($file_path).'"

and I printed the result and it's like..

[image]

but still don't work

Comment: Try converting the external images into [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: I tryed like that xlink:href="'.imageToBase64($file_path).'" but still don't work

Comment: won't that just create a string that starts '.imageTo... you need to call that function and pass its result as the xlink:href value.

Comment: Can you send me an example pls?

Comment: The link in my first comment has example data URIs

Comment: I edited the post to show my result [ like the one in your link.. ] but still dont' work

Comment: Missing space between the id attribute and the xlink:href attribute.

Comment: nothing changes with this space

Answer (score 1):

It appears that by default, ImageMagick will not download content over http/https. There are at least 2 options to make this work.

#### Option 1: Update the ImagMagick [security policy](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php).

Add the following directives to the `policy.xml` file. The [resources](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#configure) page outlines some locations where it looks for configuration files.

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="URL" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="HTTPS" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="HTTP" />
```

With these options in effect, PHP+Imagick will be able to include the remote images in the rendered image.

#### Option 2: Have PHP make local copies of the images

Another option is to have PHP (e.g. `file_get_contents`) to fetch the remote images, save a local copy, render the image, and delete the temporary image files.

This method is preferred if you can't/won't mess with the installed ImageMagick security policy.

Here is a modified loop based on your code that works:

```
$files = [];
foreach($player as $key => $id){
    $file_path = 'https://domain.it/tor/image/download/player'.$id.'.jpg';
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'im');
    $files[] = $temp_file;
    file_put_contents($temp_file, file_get_contents($file_path));
    $file_path = $temp_file;

    // update image placeholder with image from local filesystem
     $svg = preg_replace(
       '/id="player'.($key+1).'" xlink:href="svg"/'
       , 'id="player'.($key+1).'" xlink:href="' . htmlspecialchars($file_path) . '"'
       , $svg);
}

// after rendering the SVG, delete temp files
foreach($files as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```